# Escaping parentheses when sending GPG passphrase to a Perl script

Tags: perl, shell, gnupg

I am having some difficulty with a Perl script that is invoked from cron.

One of the arguments for the script is a GPG passphrase. This is later interpolated into a string that is sent to the shell.

This particular passphrase contains an open parentheses, and the script fails with a "syntax error near unexpected token `(" error.

This is the offending part of the phrase:

```
m3(ÃÝ4úÅ¤;:q!
```

I have tried single and double quoting it before the value is used in the script, but that does not have an effect.

The phrase works correctly when invoking GPG directly from the shell, just not when it gets interpolated into the following:

```
`gpg --passphrase $gpgpp --batch -o $gpgofile -d $file`;
```

Where $gpgpp is the passphrase variable.

What is the correct way to escape this, and other potentially problematic characters?

Comment: by the way, back-ticks are used to capture the output of a shell command.  If you don't want that output and just want to run the command, you should be using `system()` instead.

Comment: Never do this on a multi-user machine -- all other users can see what parameters you passed to a process. Use `--passphrase-file` or `--passphrase-fd` instead.

Comment: @JensErat this is not a multi-user machine. Thank you for the suggestion, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\Q` and `\E` escape sequences are used to escape all "special" characters between them.

```
`gpg --passphrase \Q$gpgpp\E --batch -o $gpgofile -d $file`;
```

This should be done any time you have a variable that may contain characters which need to be escaped.

http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html

Comment: Marked as answer. Thank you - supporting an existing script and my Perl experience is limited - I was not aware of these sequences!

Answer (score 1):

Enclose the variables in quotes:

```
gpg --passphrase "$gpgpp" --batch -o "$gpgofile" -d "$file"
```

Otherwise, the shell will try to interpret contents of the variables as expressions.